# MySql Rewriting Sub Query to Join

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have problem with this query:

```
SELECT Group_concat(DISTINCT titlegredcd) 
       targetGroup, 
       tblevent.id, 
       generalsubcategorynm, 
       generalcategorynm, 
       coursename, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   tblinternalstudent, 
               tblstaff 
        WHERE  eventid = tblevent.id 
               AND tblinternalstudent.staffnoic = tblstaff.staffnoic) Total, 
       Date_format(startdate, '%d %b') 
       startdateDisplay, 
       Date_format(enddate, '%d %b') 
       enddateDisplay, 
       class, 
       organizer, 
       subcategorymainorder, 
       subcategorysuborder, 
       tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalcategorycd, 
       tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalsubcategorycd 
FROM   tblevent, 
       tblcourse, 
       tblrefgeneralsubcategory, 
       tblrefgeneralcategory, 
       tblinternalstudent a, 
       tblstaff b 
WHERE  tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalcategorycd IN 
       ( 'G0001', 'G0002', 'G0003' ) 
       AND tblcourse.generalcategorycd = 
           tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalcategorycd 
       AND tblcourse.generalsubcategorycd = 
           tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalsubcategorycd 
       AND tblevent.courseid = tblcourse.courseid 
       AND tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalcategorycd = 
           tblrefgeneralcategory.generalcategorycd 
       AND a.eventid = tblevent.id 
       AND a.staffnoic = b.staffnoic 
       AND startdate >= '2012-01-01' 
       AND enddate <= '2012-12-31' 
GROUP  BY tblevent.id, 
          generalsubcategorynm, 
          generalcategorynm, 
          coursename, 
          total, 
          startdatedisplay, 
          enddatedisplay, 
          class, 
          organizer, 
          subcategorymainorder, 
          subcategorysuborder, 
          tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalcategorycd, 
          tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalsubcategorycd 
ORDER  BY tblrefgeneralsubcategory.generalsubcategorycd, 
          coursename
```

It is taking about 30 minutes to process and I suspect the problem comes from the sub select.

I try to rewrite using join:

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.courseid, 
       internalstaff.targetgroup, 
       internalstaff.total, 
       Date_format(startdate, '%d %b') AS startdateDisplay, 
       Date_format(enddate, '%d %b')   AS enddateDisplay, 
       class, 
       organizer, 
       coursename, 
       gs.generalcategorycd, 
       gs.generalsubcategorycd, 
       gs.generalsubcategorynm, 
       gs.subcategorymainorder, 
       gs.subcategorysuborder, 
       generalcategorynm 
FROM   tblcourse c, 
       tblrefgeneralsubcategory gs, 
       tblrefgeneralcategory g, 
       tblevent e 
       JOIN (SELECT i.eventid, 
                    Count(*)                           AS Total, 
                    Group_concat(DISTINCT titlegredcd) AS TargetGroup 
             FROM   tblinternalstudent i, 
                    tblstaff s 
             WHERE  i.staffnoic = s.staffnoic 
             GROUP  BY i.eventid) AS internalstaff 
         ON internalstaff.eventid = e.id 
WHERE  e.courseid = c.courseid 
       AND gs.generalcategorycd = g.generalcategorycd 
       AND gs.generalcategorycd IN ( 'G0001', 'G0002', 'G0003' ) 
       AND c.generalcategorycd = gs.generalcategorycd 
       AND c.generalsubcategorycd = gs.generalsubcategorycd 
       AND startdate >= '2012-01-01' 
       AND enddate <= '2012-12-31' 
GROUP  BY e.id, 
          generalsubcategorynm, 
          generalcategorynm, 
          startdatedisplay, 
          enddatedisplay, 
          class, 
          organizer, 
          subcategorymainorder, 
          subcategorysuborder, 
          generalcategorycd, 
          generalsubcategorycd 
ORDER  BY generalsubcategorycd, 
          coursename
```

It loads faster and returns the right number of records as the original query(1802). However when I add BranchCd (and branchcd = 'some branch code') in the internalstaff table, it will return less number of records(519).

But in the original query, if (and branchcd = 'some branch code') is added to the sub select it return the right number of records.

Can anyone please advice on how to rewrite the join so it works like the sub select?

Thank you.

Edited:
Sorry forgot to include the tables:

```
tblinternalstudent (**staffnoic**, eventid)
tblstaff (**staffnoic** titlegredcd, branchcd, unitcd)
tblevent (**id**, courseid, startdate, enddate, class, organizer)
tblcourse (**courseid**, coursename)
tblrefgeneralcategory (**generalcategorycd**, generalcategorynm)
tblrefgeneralsubcategory (**generalsubcategorycd, generalsubcategorynm, generalcategorycd,subcategorymainorder, subcategorysuborder)
```

The EXPLAIN for original query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: a
       type: ALL
       possible_keys: NULL
       key: NULL
       key_len: NULL
       ref: NULL
       rows: 38760
       Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: b
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 44
       ref: edu_db.a.StaffNoIC
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: tblEvent
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 32
       ref: edu_db.a.EventId
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: tblcourse
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 30
       ref: edu_db.tblEvent.courseid
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: tblRefGeneralSubCategory
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 34
       ref: edu_db.tblcourse.GeneralSubCategoryCd,edu_db.tblcourse.GeneralCategoryCd
       rows: 1
       Extra:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: tblRefGeneralCategory
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 17
       ref: edu_db.tblcourse.GeneralCategoryCd
       rows: 1
       Extra:
*************************** 7. row ***************************
       id: 2
       select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
       table: tblinternalstudent
       type: ALL
       possible_keys: NULL
       key: NULL
       key_len: NULL
       ref: NULL
       rows: 38760
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 8. row ***************************
       id: 2
       select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
       table: tblStaff
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 44
       ref: edu_db.tblinternalstudent.StaffNoIC
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where; Using index
```

The EXPLAIN for second query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: <derived2>
       type: ALL
       possible_keys: NULL
       key: NULL
       key_len: NULL
       ref: NULL
       rows: 8849
      Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: e
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 32
       ref: internalstaff.eventid
       rows: 1
      Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: c
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 30
       ref: edu_db.e.courseid
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: gs
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 34
       ref: edu_db.c.GeneralSubCategoryCd,edu_db.c.GeneralCategor
       rows: 1
       Extra:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
       id: 1
       select_type: PRIMARY
       table: g
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 17
       ref: edu_db.gs.GeneralCategoryCd
       rows: 1
       Extra: Using where
*************************** 6. row ***************************
       id: 2
       select_type: DERIVED
       table: i
       type: ALL
       possible_keys: NULL
       key: NULL
       key_len: NULL
       ref: NULL
       rows: 38760
       Extra: Using filesort
*************************** 7. row ***************************
       id: 2
       select_type: DERIVED
       table: s
       type: eq_ref
       possible_keys: PRIMARY
       key: PRIMARY
       key_len: 44
       ref: edu_db.i.StaffNoIC
       rows: 1
```

Comment: Please post the `EXPLAIN` for each statement and the indexes for involved tables.

Comment: why are you using cartisian query. Why don't you use joins? And post your schema and desired output. This query can be much simplified with joins and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query also there might be some relation problem as you haven't clearly told here.

```
SELECT
  te.id,
  Date_format(startdate, '%d %b') AS startdateDisplay,
  Date_format(enddate, '%d %b') AS enddateDisplay,
  te.class,
  te.organizer,
  tgs.generalcategorycd,
  tgs.generalsubcategorycd,
  tgs.generalsubcategorynm,
  tgs.subcategorymainorder,
  tgs.subcategorysuborder,
  trc.generalcategorynm,
  count(tic.*)             AS `Total`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tic. titlegredcd) AS TargetGroup
FROM tblevent AS te
  LEFT JOIN tblinternalstudent AS tis
    ON tis.eventid = te.id
  LEFT JOIN tblstaff AS ts
    ON ts.staffnoic = tis.staffnoic
  LEFT JOIN tblcourse AS tc
    ON tc.courseid = te.courseid
  LEFT JOIN tblrefgeneralsubcategory AS tgs
    ON tgs.generalcategorycd = tc.generalcategorycd
  LEFT JOIN tblrefgeneralcategory AS trc
    ON trc.generalcategorycd = tgs.generalcategorycd
WHERE te.startdate >= '2012-01-01'
    AND te.enddate <= '2012-12-31'
    AND trc.generalcategorycd IN('G0001', 'G0002', 'G0003')
GROUP BY te.id, tgs.generalsubcategorynm, trc.generalcategorynm, te.startdatedisplay, te.enddatedisplay te.class, te.organizer, tgs.subcategorymainorder, tgs.subcategorysuborder, trc.generalcategorycd, tgs.generalsubcategorycd
ORDER BY tgs.generalsubcategorycd, tc.coursename
```